# Hard disk doesn't show up on Windows 10, but it shows up on Windows 7 - Symbol of deactivation

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Since yesterday my hard drive doesn't show up on Windows 10, only on Windows 7.

In Device Management, in correspondence of the hard drive item, there is the symbol (circle with inside a black arrow pointing down) that appears when a device is disabled, but my hard drive is enabled. I tried to disable it and then re-enable it, but the symbol is still there.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it in another USB port? If it doesn't work, try to unplug it (in Windows 10), shutdown your PC, plug the drive while the PC is off, then start the PC on Windows 10 again. Could be your USB controller needs a new driver. Could also be Windows 10 didn't enable the device for other reasons (that's what the icon means: "Device not enabled"). Right-click on the line of your USB drive, and see if there's an option to "Enable device" or its equivalent in Italian.

Comment: Hi @Didier, I followed your strategy, but the problem persists.

Comment: OK, you are going to have to check in the BIOS/UEFI what's up with USB ports, but before that, go to your Contol Panel, in System and security > Power options/management, click on Change mode parameters (the link on the right), then on Edit advanced parameters, then expand the USB section, and if you find an option to selectively suspend USB devices to save power, disable/deactivate it. If that doesn't work, we'll have to visit your BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: My USB ports are ok, in fact i have other hard drives and they work correctly.

Comment: Maybe this specific hard drive needs either a separate power source, or more power than your motherboard can deliver under its current settings. Disabling selective USB suspension can ease things a bit. Otherwise, we'll need to go under the hood...